# htaccess - redirect one step back to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect to the same link, but one step back?

Example:

From  `example.com/whatever/thing/` to `example.com/whatever/`

(where "thing" is always the same word)

Only when coming from outside domain and word "thing" is at the end.

Comment: "Only when comming from outside domain" - What do you mean by this? Are you suggesting that when coming from "inside the domain" the user shouldn't be redirected? (Although I'm not sure what that would mean either?)

Comment: Redirection should occur only when a visitor arrived directly to that page, from another site (domain).

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/thing/$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

This redirects `/<whatever>/thing/` to `/<whatever>/`, where `<whatever>` is variable and `thing` is a fixed string, only when the user navigates to this URL from an external site.

However, the `Referer` is unreliable. It's possible that a referring site sets a Referrer-Policy that completely suppresses the `Referer` header being sent. (You can't reasonably block an empty `Referer`.)